# How to manage SWRevealViewController with button

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift3, swrevealviewcontroller

I tried to implemented the [SWRevealViewController](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController) to my project, but I want to do it with a button and all documentations I found are for barbuttonitems that have this code:

```
detailButton.target = revealViewController()
detailButton.action = #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:))
```

How can I do it with a simple button?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

do like

```
let revealViewController = self.revealViewController()
var settingsButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
settingsButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "settings_icon")!, for: .normal)
settingsButton.addTarget(revealViewController, action: #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
View.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this(For ObjC)

```
- (IBAction)onBtn:(id)sender {
[self.btn addTarget:self.revealViewController action:@selector(revealToggle:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
 }
```